# Flutter Exception caught by widgets library error and Stack Overflow with red color in simulator

Tags: flutter

I'm new at stackoverflow, please warn me If I have missing information in my code.

I wrote some codes but in simulator, it giving error as in photo I added.

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(const TodoApp());
}

class TodoApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const TodoApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Todo Uygulaması',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.pink,
        ),
        home: TodoApp()

        //TodoList(title: 'Todo Uygulaması'),
        );
  }
}

class TodoList extends StatefulWidget {
  TodoList({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<TodoList> createState() => _TodoListState();
}

enum moreVert { rechange, delete }

TextEditingController t1 = TextEditingController();
List TodoVerileri = [];

class _TodoListState extends State<TodoList> {
  void veriEkle() {
    setState(() {
      TodoVerileri.add(t1.text);
      t1.clear();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(
          child: ListTile(
        onTap: () {},
        title: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
          child: Text('Todo'),
        ),
      )),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[Tasks()],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: _FloatingActionButton(context),
    );
  }

  Flexible Tasks() {
    return Flexible(
        child: ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, indexnum) => Row(
        children: [
          ListTile(title: Text(TodoVerileri[indexnum])),
        ],
      ),
      itemCount: TodoVerileri.length,
    ));
  }

  FloatingActionButton _FloatingActionButton(BuildContext context) {
    return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        pressFun(context);
      },
      tooltip: 'Increment',
      child: const Icon(Icons.add),
    );
  }

  Future<dynamic> pressFun(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
              title: const Text("Type Your Task Here"),
              actions: [
                TextField(
                  controller: t1,
                ),
                Center(
                    child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                          veriEkle();
                        },
                        child: Text('Create'))),
                Center(
                    child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                        child: Text('Cancel')))
              ],
            ));
  }
}

class PopUpMen extends StatefulWidget {
  const PopUpMen({super.key});

  @override
  State<PopUpMen> createState() => _PopUpMenState();
}

class _PopUpMenState extends State<PopUpMen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopupMenuButton(
      onSelected: (value) {
        // your logic
      },
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext bc) {
        return const [
          PopupMenuItem(
              child: Row(
            children: [Icon(Icons.edit), Text('Edit')],
          )),
          PopupMenuItem(
              child: Row(
            children: [Icon(Icons.delete), Text('Delete')],
          )),
        ];
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Error code:

Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4809 pos 16: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/o14Wl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Preferred Solution

Remove the Row widget and just use the ListTile:

```
Flexible Tasks() {
    return Flexible(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, indexnum) => ListTile(title: Text(TodoVerileri[indexnum])),
        itemCount: TodoVerileri.length,
      ),
    );
  }
```

## Alternative Solution 1

You need to update your Tasks widget to this (Wrap the ListTile in an Expanded):

```
Flexible Tasks() {
    return Flexible(
        child: ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, indexnum) => Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(child: ListTile(title: Text(TodoVerileri[indexnum]))),
        ],
      ),
      itemCount: TodoVerileri.length,
    ));
  }
```

When you have a ListTile directly inside of a Row, it doesn't know exactly how wide it can be.

## Alternative Solution 2

Wrap your ListTile in a SizedBox and explicitly set the width to the width of the screen:

```
Flexible Tasks() {
    return Flexible(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, indexnum) => Row(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: ListTile(title: Text(TodoVerileri[indexnum]))),
          ],
        ),
        itemCount: TodoVerileri.length,
      ),
    );
  }
```